# Whats the code to create a no limit table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, limit

I want to create an html table but it must not have limits in sides.

Can you help me?

Comment: You want to do what now?

Comment: its like a table that fills the whole screen from sides, but still with limits above and bellow

Comment: It's still very unclear what you want. Try drawing a quick image, and editing it into your question.

Comment: I think maybe (guessing) the OP wants either a paginated or scrolling table. (?)

Comment: Perhaps you mean a table of limited height but unlimited width - perhaps that expands in width to enclose its contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table width="100%">
<tr><td>cell content</td></tr>
</table>
```